# Find out URL response to check broken Url's in Codeception

Tags: codeception

I have fetched multiple URL's using grabMultiple() method.
I want to check its response to check whether it is broken(i.e.404) or not.

Can I use HTTP Response in Codeception ? If yes what is the syntax ?

Comment: You would get fewer downvotes if you stopped tagging PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me -

```
function check_url($link){

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10); //follow up to 10 redirections - avoids loops
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
preg_match_all("/HTTP\/1\.[1|0]\s(\d{3})/",$data,$matches);

$code = end($matches[1]);

if($code==404) 
{
    echo "Bad url";
}
else{
    echo "Good url";
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Use [seeResponseCodeIs](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser#seeResponseCodeIs) method.

```
$links = $I->grabMultiple('div.test-info a', 'href');
foreach ($links as $link) {
  $I->amOnPage($link);
  $I->seeResponseCodeIs(\Codeception\Util\HttpCode::OK);
}
```